# Evitar que el usuario pueda sacar archivos de una carpeta de Windows C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows10, filesystem

Estoy realizando una aplicación en C# para el control de carpetas, actualmente lo estoy realizando con `FileSystemWatch` pero eso solo me permite saber que se ha introducido/movido/sacado el archivo pero quiero evitar que el usuario pueda introducir o sacar determinados tipos de archivos.
Algunas aplicaciones como OneDrive o Dropbox sí que lo controlan:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Conoceis con qué librería podría hacer esto? En principio el objetivo es que usuarios no autorizados no puedan sacar ni meter archivos solo visualizarlos.

Comment: No creo que puedas conseguirlo mediante programación, ya que es parte intrínseca del sistema operativo. Quizá podrías mediante politicas de windows, pero si los usuarios deben tener acceso de lectura a los archivos, podrán copiarles.

Comment: @Pikoh gracias, y forma de impedir que entren archivos que no tengan una extensión (por ejemplo .pdf)? Una vez los detecto los muevo, pero quiero evitar que los puedan meter directamente. No estaría impdiendo lectura sino entrada.

Comment: Tal vez sea mas sencillo poner permiso de escritura en la carpeta solo para administradores. Pero no soy ningun experto en sistemas lo siento :)

Comment: claramente esto que planteas no se resuelve usando codigo, quizas se pueda limitar por medio de las GPO de windows https://www.lepide.com/how-to/assign-permissions-to-files-folders-through-group-policy.html  pero deberias verlo con un admin de red

Comment: Creo que lo normal es bloquear USB a las máquinas y el internet cerrarlo sólo a lo que necesitan, esa es la solución barata. La cara es contratar un software que cifra todo el contenido de la maquina y cuando lo sacan a otra simplemente no se puede leer.